# Heroku error with installing installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, heroku, rubygems

I created a small Rails app and I want to deploy it. I am getting a error when pushing to Heroku. I know this question has been asked already, but none of the solutions are working for me. I am on Ubuntu. This is what the error says :

```
 Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Here is the Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'



# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'pg'
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: have you tryed the command `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` before `bundle install`

Comment: Yeah and I get the same error still..

Comment: create a new gemset and try to use different gemset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I think the problem was that I was installing the production gems locally and this was causing errors with Heroku. I updated my gemfile then ran bundle update and then the major step was to run `bundle install --without production`.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conflict between using postgresql and sqlite3 in your Rails app. You've set sqlite3 to run in development and test but also wrote postgresql to run in production, development, and test. I would suggest specifying the postgresql gem to run in production only.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I had a problem similar to this, but with installing the pg gem, and to solve it, I had to run sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev first, before running bundle install. I am not sure if this is the case with this problem as well.

Comment: Have you tried just installing `gem install sqlite3` then running `bundle install`?